# How to calculate PSD if i have power vs freq spectrum?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, python, power-spectral-density, frequency, scipy

i have a signal something like this

[image]

how to calculate PSD?

i have freq from 191000200 to 196500000

time gap or delta t = *1 or 2 sec*, (what i mean is [tn] - [tn-1])
i will be computing in python any suggestion from scipy or any lib will be helpful

thanks in advance

Comment: With this amount of information: not at all; you can plot these five values, you can average them, interpolate between at will, but without any information what they mean and how they were measured, no chance of estimating a PSD. Everything you claim could be right or wrong. This needs way more information about where these numbers come from.

Comment: If those are dBm (and not mdB, which I've never heard of), I'd suggest reviewing your calculations.

Comment: Yes that's dBm only. Sorry my typo

Comment: @LTpy um, if that's dBm, then they're totally utterly wrong.

Comment: @LTpy so, this has to be broken: If you receive only a **single** 191 MHz photon **per year**, then  you'd have a power of roughly -324 dBm. So, you're more than worlds off here in your values, and as sad, without any meaning to what you do, we really can only wildly guess what this has to do with a PSD. Vote to close as unclear, sadly.

Comment: A picture of more broken values with no info how you came to them doesn't make your question any better, sorry.

Comment: this comes from waveanalyser, why is it broken you are saying?

Comment: @LTpy because these values are physically impossible, as I explained above. I don't know "waveanalyser", but you'll need to figure out what exactly it calculates, and how.

Answer (score -1):

i used this formula saw on wiki, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density

it works okay for me, [image]

thanks for the comments, it helped me to understand the data what I was receiving.